# Undefined when I try to get Text on a tspan element [WDIO] - typescript

Tags: undefined, wdio

I'm not able to get the text from a Tspan element, at the moment to see the value im getting undefined.

`const element = await  $("g.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-line-series.highcharts-color-undefined.highcharts-series-1 tspan");`

`await testElement.isDisplayed();`

`await testElement.getText();`
**undefined**

Answer (score 0):

we probably need more context of your issue to give you a better answer.

As far as I can see in your post, you are trying to wait for the element to be displayed with this sentence:

```
await testElement.isDisplayed();
```

But this sentence doesn't wait for the element, it only returns the current state of the element.

If you want to wait for the element, you should try with the native wdio waits:

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForDisplayed

So that line would turn into:

```
await testElement.waitForDisplayed();
```